# How do I not repeat my code inside Laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, search, laravel-8, laravel-blade

I created a search form inside my navbar, which I included inside my main blade (`app.blade`) using `@include()` and I want the search button to work inside all my blades without repeating my code.

Right now I wrote it in `index.blade` just to see how it works, and in order to make it work when accessing it from the `category.blade` for example, I have to copy the code inside the `view-category()` function and so on.

I would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: Do you mean with (repeated code) the search functionality ? that should be in controller ?

Answer (score 0):

The search form request should be processed by a function in your controller, who just going to process the data and display them on a result page.

The process looks like that:

```
The search component you include -> post request -> process the request in your controller -> display the result
```

So in theory, you should not have duplicate code

Comment: Thank you so much! I realised what I was doing wrong. I had not create a route for the search form.

Comment: No problem, don't forget to set the question solved with my answer :)